# Sort a varchar converted datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a `datetime` column, dates are shown like "11/13/2012 1:48:27 PM" I need to convert it to "11/13/12".

I know I can convert it using

```
convert(varchar(10), datevalue, 1)
```

but when I sort the column after converting it's not sorting by date. I'm not sure if `convert(datetime, datevalue, 1)` is supposed to do anything but nothing happenend and I still got the default date value.

I tried this

```
select convert(varchar(10), datevalue, 1) 
from table 
order by convert(datetime, datevalue, 1) desc
```

It works but my bigger query selects distinct and I'm getting an error

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified

Comment: convert after sorting.

Comment: Show your "bigger query". You have one column in DISTINCT wich is not in ORDER BY. Add it and it should work.

Comment: You can also try casting it to the `DATE` type instead of casting it to the varchar `CAST(datevalue as date)`

Comment: @CoderofCode i'm using sqlserver 2005, the date datatype isn't supported yet.

Comment: Ideally, leave the data as datetime data here and only convert it into a text format closer to the user (i.e. in the application or the reporting tool that is *consuming* the results of your query)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever This is what I just ended up doing, I'm still wondering if there's a way to do it on the query alone.

Comment: It depends - is the requirement "convert the date to this format" or "remove the time component of the date"? That second one can easily be accommodated in the query.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It's convert to the specified format and sort the results by date

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), datevalue, 1) 
FROM table 
ORDER BY datevalue desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, datevalue, 103) 
FROM table
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, datevalue, 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(varchar(10), datevalue, 1) 
from table 
order by datevalue desc
```

You don't need to convert date in `order by` statement. Only column name would work if its datatype is 'datetime'